# starting script in background

Tags: weblogic, jython, wlst

the problem:

starting a bash script in background when in another script. the script is used to start the weblogic nodemanager.

the attempts:

command line it will launch without a hitch

```
./startNodeManager.sh &
```

when in a bash script it works as well:

```
cat startNMScript.sh
./startNodeManager11G.sh &
```

execution:

```
./startNMScript.sh
```

however, neither of these options work when I call them from a WLST(Jython 2.2.1) where subprocess isn't supported, and exporting the module from another install doesn't work.
I have used os.system('startNodeManager11G.sh &') and os.system('startNMScript.sh').

results are either that it won't start, and continue the script, or that it will start, but stop as soon as I kill the script, which will hang after execution of that line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to start the nodemanager through WLST (and make sure it doesn't die), use `nohup`:

```
nohup ./startNodeManager.sh > nodemanager_log.out &
```